# load test data in pytorch

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

All is in the title, I just want to know, how can I load my own test data (image.jpg) in pytorch in order to test my CNN.

Answer (score 1):

You need to feed images to net the same as in training: that is, you should apply exactly the same transformations to get similar results.

Assuming your net was trained using [this code](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/imagenet/main.py) (or similar), you can see that an input image (for validation) undergoes the following [transformations](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/imagenet/main.py#L210-L215):

> ```
> transforms.Compose([
>             transforms.Resize(256),
>             transforms.CenterCrop(224),
>             transforms.ToTensor(),
>             normalize,
>         ])),
> ```

Following [`torchvision.transforms`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html) docs you can see that an input image goes through:

- Resizing to 256x256 pix
- Cropping 224x224 rect from the center of the image
- The image is converted from uint8 datatype to float in range `[0, 1]`, and transposed to 3-by-224-by-224 array
- The image is [normalize](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/imagenet/main.py#L188-l189) by subtracting mean and dividing by std.

You can do all this manually to any image

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

pil_img = Image.open('image.jpg').resize((256, 256), Image.BILINEAR)  # read and resize
# center crop
w, h = pil_img.size
i = int(round((h - 224) / 2.))
j = int(round((w - 224) / 2.))
pil_img = pil_img.crop((j, i, j+224, i+224))
np_img = np.array(pil_img).astype(np.float32) / 255.
np_img = np.transpose(np_img, (2, 0, 1))  
# normalize
mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
for c in range(3):
  np_img = (np_img[c, ...] - mean[c]) / std[c]
```

Once you have `np_img` ready for your model, you can run a feed forward pass:

```
pred = model(np_img[None, ...])  # note that we add a singleton leading dim for batch
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your response. My problem was loading test data and **I found a solution**.

```
test_data = datasets.ImageFolder('root/test_cnn', transform=transform)
```

For example if I have 2 directories cat & dog (in the test_cnn directory) that contains images, the Object ImageFolder will assign automatically the classes cat and dog to my images.

During testing, I have just to drop the classes.